# My xcode app is not installed on my iPhone, what can i do?

Tags: iphone, xcode

i don't have a jailbraked iPhone and i don't want to jailbrake it for now. I convert my myAppName.app application to myAppName.ipa. I load my app on iTunes but when i sync, the app is not installed on my iPhone. My iPhone iOS is iOS 6, i make apps on Xcode 4.4.1 so on iOS 5.1, so i can't run my app on my iPhone from Xcode.

Can someone tell me how can i solve this problem?

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: How do you "convert" your app to ipa? I hope you don't just change the extension?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. :-) You don't do it through iTunes; you deploy from XCode itself. This [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2469890/62576) has info about the provisioning profile you need to create to do so, and a link to the docs about it.

Comment: No. I did as below

1. open Iphone Explorer
2. copy my_app_name.app to Desktop
3. create a folder
4. rename the folder to Payload
5. move my_app_name.app to Payload
6. compress Payload
7. rename the Payload.zip to Payload.ipa
8. rename Paylaod.ipa to my_app_name.ipa

Comment: "My iPhone iOS is iOS 6, i make apps on Xcode 4.4.1 so on iOS 5.1, so i can't run my app on my iPhone from Xcode."  Why not?

Comment: I can't run my app on my iPhone from Xcode because the version of iOS on my iPhone does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to run your app on iPhone. Correct? If that's the case, you will have to purchase a membership on develop.apple.com. Once you have done that follow the steps on: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUdHifLTyrE&feature=BFa&list=PLdtvnlkHu09KgpdUgjkUnoTWqwTcqKGGH . I recommend following this video because the steps have been explained very clearly and if you follow it carefully, chances are you will be able to run your app in the first shot.

Also, if you using Xcode 4.5 to develop apps and running them on 3.5" screen, please uncheck "Use Autolayout" under File Inspector. For more info, please check: [presentViewController: crash on iOS <6 (AutoLayout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198981/presentviewcontroller-crash)

Hope this answers your question! All the best!

Comment: @panosbt: if you find my answer useful, I would appreciate if you kindly accept it. I too am new to stackoverflow and I would be happy to gain some reputation points.